# Why there is no ZA acoustic mode in bulk 3D materials whereas it appears in 2D materials (monolayer type)?

Tags: electronic-band-theory, phonons

For each materials phonon band structure there are three acoustic phonon bands (2-LA and 1-TA for bulk or ZA,TA and LA for 2D materials).
Now, I have this straightforward question that "Why there is no ZA acoustic mode in bulk 3D materials whereas it appears in 2D materials (monolayer type)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the numbers wrong. There are two transverse acoustic (TA) and one longitudinal acoustic (LA) phonons in bulk solids.

In the case of monolayer materials, like graphene, it is common to call the out-of-plane direction $z$ so that the $z$-polarized TA phonon is called the ZA phonon. This is just a matter of notation since the $z$ direction is special in highly two-dimensional materials.